# How many nodes the ES cluster can contain? The maximum number

Tags: cluster-computing, elasticsearch

I am curious about the maximum number of nodes which the ES cluster can contain? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical limitation on the number of nodes is the amount of resources:

- Each node needs to exist in the `cluster state` which is a data structure present on all nodes, and thus consumes a small amount of heap space.
- And all nodes maintain a network connection to all other nodes

So practically, you could scale to thousands of nodes quite easily.